# Newly installed led down lights turning off together

Tags: led

We have two separate circuits in a new extension, each has 10 dimmable led down lights and goes through a dimmer switch (again separately) they work fine when first switched on but after a while will randomly turn one of the circuits off ( it can be either set)and then go back on a few seconds later. The dimmer switch is rated over the amperage of the lights (4w x 10) the dimmer switch was changed and still doing it. Any advice?

Comment: Does it do this at any brightness, or just towards minimum? Does the dimmer have a trim control [some are manual, some electronic]? Is it specifically designed to handle LEDs?

Comment: What make and model is your dimmer, and what make and model are the LED fixtures involved?

Comment: Could be a wiring problem, wire is getting warm and losing connection.  (though, on only 16 watts / 0.13 amps??? Maybe wire in the downlight enclosure that's getting a bit warm from LED??)